# server side timer on every 3 minutes in current timer for a bet making game node js with unique game id

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, sockets

[sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNS7D.png) i am creating a bet game in node js back end and angular for front end where number of users can choose any number from current game and after timer end they will get result and reward point. After game end, timer is restart from 3 minutes with new game. And if new user will come here, he can see real time left of game. What is best logic to get this approach?
i added  UI of my game in link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the timer, you could calculate the game end time and then send it to the client... For example, if the game starts at 14:30:05, you send 14:33:05 to the client. I recommend you a library called MomentJS

```js
let endTime = 0;
let timer;

function startGame() {
  endTime = moment().add(3, 'minutes'); // Current time + 3 minutes
  console.log('game started at', moment.now())
}

function renderTimer() {
  // This goes on the client side
  clearInterval(timer); // If you hit start game again you need to clear the loop
  timer = setInterval(function(){  $('#h1').text(moment(moment(endTime).diff(moment())).format('mm:ss')); }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- MomentJS -->
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="startGame()">Start game</button>
<button onclick="renderTimer()">Get timer</button>


<h1 id="h1"></h1>
```